# Remove Number and period in filename vbsript

Tags: vbscript, filenames

I have already found a script that will replace underscore (_) and other text that I write in script. I need to modify this script so that it will also remove all the numbers in the filename too. I tried [0-9] and /d but that didn't remove the numbers in the filename. Also I tried to remove a period in the file name, but that also removed the file extension. So it took away the .csv too. Can someone help?

```
'========================================================
' VBScript to replace underscore in file name with space 
' for each files in a folder
' Written by ApOgEE of http://coderstalk.blogspot.com
'========================================================
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol

' create the filesystem object
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' get current folder
Set fol = fso.GetFolder(".")

' go thru each files in the folder
For Each fil In fol.Files
    ' check if the file name contains underscore
    If InStr(1, fil.Name, "_") <> 0 Then
        ' replace underscore with space
        sName = Replace(fil.Name, "_", " ")
        ' rename the file
        fil.Name = sName
    End If
Next

' echo the job is completed
WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

Comment: I did: sName = Replace(SName, ".", "") to try and replace the period. Also sName = Replace(SName, "[0-9]", "") to remove numbers

Answer (score 2):

The [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29) function does only simple string replacements. It doesn't support wildcards or patterns. You're looking for [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29):

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[0-9_.]"
re.Global  = True

For Each fil In fol.Files
  fil.Name = re.Replace(fil.Name, " ")
Next
```